# How to merge records for query set

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, group-concatenation

We have a question related to a DB query :

```
CREATE TABLE `Action` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `updated_action_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `notes` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  KEY `action_empId_fk` (`emp_Id`),

  CONSTRAINT `action_empId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_Id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=502004 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `ActionAssignedTo` (
  `action_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `actionassignedto_emp_id_foreign` (`emp_Id`),
  KEY `actionassignedto_action_id_foreign` (`action_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ActionAssignedTo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_Id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ActionAssignedTo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`action_Id`) REFERENCES `Action` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vendor_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_Number` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `updated_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `employee_vendor_id_foreign` (`vendor_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_vendor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_Id`) REFERENCES `Vendor` (`vendor_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=511 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

We want to find the action created by employee with Action.empId = 4 along with the list of Assignee (an action can be assigned to multiple people)

We have the following query :

```
Select     notes, 
           Action.id, 
           AssigneeName.name, 
           ActionAssignedTo.emp_Id 
from       Employee
inner join Action 
on         (Action.emp_Id = Employee.id 
and        Action.emp_Id in (select Employee.id 
                             from Employee 
                             where Employee.vendor_Id = 1))
inner      join ActionAssignedTo 
on         Action.id =  ActionAssignedTo.action_Id
inner join Employee as AssigneeName 
on         ActionAssignedTo.emp_Id =  AssigneeName.id
where      Action.emp_Id = 4
```

Now, lets say if Action with id = 10 was assigned to 2 people : John (empId : 2) And Jack (empId : 5) --> the above query returns following results :

(columns from the query)

```
notes                       | Action.id | AssigneeName.name | ActionAssignedTo.emp_Id
1. Finish Designing Queries | 10        | John              | 2
2. Finish Designing Queries | 10        | Jack              | 5
```

If we observe the above results the first 2 columns get repeated for the Assignees for SAME ACTION ID  --> is there a way we can merge them something like

```
1. Finish Designing Queries |10         | { John : 2  , Jack  : 5}
```

Basically records being merged into one.

Comment: See my tips on [_many:many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by using group_concat()

> ```
> create table t (notes varchar(200), id int, name varchar(100), emp_Id int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values ('1. Finish Designing Queries', 10, 'John', 2);
> insert into t values ('2. Finish Designing Queries', 10, 'Jack', 5);
> insert into t values ('3. Other note', 20, 'Jack', 5);
> ```

> ```
> select notes, id, group_concat(name, ':', emp_id)
> from   t
> group by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> notes                       | id | group_concat(name, ':', emp_id)
> :-------------------------- | -: | :------------------------------
> 1. Finish Designing Queries | 10 | John:2,Jack:5                  
> 3. Other note               | 20 | Jack:5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=85703703f61f026a6579752d8858ea32)*

Comment: Thank you @McNets. I will try this code in my db.  Just keen to know does group_concat cause any perf issues.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: In the above example if I only wanted name field, so I just use group_concat(name) --> Is there a way we can get this in form of array rather than comma separated values

Comment: On MySQL 5.7 you can use JSON_ARRAY, unfortunately I can't use this fiddle to show up an example.

Comment: McNets : I  tried fidgeting and had a small question  :
We get output as "["a"],["b"],["c"],["d"]"   when we use group_concat (json_array(DB_FIELD))

and we get ["a,b,c,d"] when we use json_array(group_concat(DB_FIELD))

we have done a group by DB_FIELD in both cases.

We are actually expecting something like this : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

Can you guide us what are we missing

Comment: In MySQL 5.7.22 there is a [JSON_OBJECTAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) maybe it could be useful
And JSON_ARRAYAGG

Comment: @j10 have a look at this: http://rextester.com/XMTM70410

Comment: That was very helpful @McNets.

Comment: can you check this as well : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211121/getting-the-query-right

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but it was a bit long for a comment so I'll add it here. If not mistaken, since:

```
from       Employee
inner join Action 
    on         (Action.emp_Id = Employee.id 
    and        Action.emp_Id in (select Employee.id 
                         from Employee 
                         where Employee.vendor_Id = 1))
```

we can rewrite this to:

```
    on         (Action.emp_Id = Employee.id 
    and        Employee.id in (select Employee.id 
                         from Employee 
                         where Employee.vendor_Id = 1))
```

and:

```
    on         (Action.emp_Id = Employee.id 
    and        Employee.vendor_Id = 1
```

Which should save you one table access to Employee.

Comment: good suggestion @Lennart